# O que é um hook method?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método

Estou estudando alguns padrões de projeto e me deparei com esse método, porem, seu conceito não ficou claro para mim.
O que faz o método e qual a relação entre ele e o Template Method?
Gostaria de um exemplo em java.
Trecho que não entendi:

> hook methods são métodos que permitem extensão.
>   A superclasse possui um método principal público que é invocado pelos seus clientes.
>   Esse método delega parte de sua execução para o hook method, que é um método abstrato que deve ser implementado pela subclasse...

Comment: Poderia colocar um trecho do material que cita isso?

Comment: @Pablo Ai esta  o trecho.

Comment: Entendi. Estou escrevendo a resposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esses métodos *hook* citados são usados no padrão Template. Assim como o trecho que você citou menciona, existe uma classe abstrata `A` que delega partes de sua funcionalidade para métodos abstratos. Uma classe concreta `B` que herda dessa classe precisa implementar esses métodos para que o código compile. Veja um exemplo:

```
public abstract class MinhaClasseAbstrata {
    public abstract int porcaoPersonalizada(String parametro);

    public int acaoPrincipal(String parametro) {
        return parametro.length() + porcaoPersonalizada(parametro);
    }
}

public MinhaClasseConcreta extends MinhaClasseAbstrata {

    public int porcaoPersonalizada(String parametro) {
        return parametro.length() + 55; // um cálculo qualquer específico para esse caso
    }

}


public MinhaOutraClasseConcreta extends MinhaClasseAbstrata {

    public int porcaoPersonalizada(String parametro) {
        return parametro.length() + 23; // um cálculo qualquer específico para esse caso
    }

}
```

Dessa forma, você sabe que pode chamar `acaoPersonalizada` em qualquer exemplar da classe `MinhaClasseAbstrata` que haverá, garantidamente, um retorno, baseado na definição de `porcaoPersonalizada` do tipo concreto do objeto em questão.

Comment: Valeu pela atenção cara! Mas poderia explicar essa parte:  "que delega partes de sua funcionalidade para métodos abstratos..." O que significa delegar uma parte?

Comment: É meio que uma expressão bonita para "chamar outro método para fazer o trabalho". :)

Comment: @Poderia fazer uma pequena analogia na sua resposta sobre o Template method  e o hook method?

Comment: Poderia fazer uma analogia entre o hook method e o Template method em sua resposta? Obrigado!!

Comment: Não são coisas comparáveis. Uma coisa faz parte da outra. Hook é o nome pelo qual chamamos esses métodos que são chamados pela classe abstrata.

Comment: Agora percebi que eu tinha escrito de forma confusa. Releia a primeira frase que eu editei e veja se está claro.

Answer (score 5):

O "Hook Method" atua como um placeholder dentro "Template Method".

Isso quer dizer que é um método declarado na classe base, mas somente é definido nas classes derivadas.

Dê uma olhada mais a fundo neste link, que explica sobre o Template Method Pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method